# Trouble to calculate a $\| \;\; \|_{L^1}$ norm ($\int\limits_0^1 n e^{-nx}dx$)

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Let $I = (0, 1)$ and $f_n(x) = n e^{-nx}$ a sequence of functions. I calculated $\|f_n\|_1$ and I obtained two different aswers.

$$\|f_n\|_1 = \int\limits_0^1 |f_n(x)| dx = \int\limits_0^1 n e^{-nx} dx = - \int\limits_0^1 (e^{-nx})' dx = -e^{-nx} \Big|_0^1 = -e^{-n} + 1$$
and with change of variable $x \to \frac{x}{n}$
$$\|f_n\|_1 = \int\limits_0^1 |f_n(x)| dx = \int\limits_0^1 n e^{-nx} dx = \int\limits_0^1 n e^{-x} \frac{1}{n} dx = \int\limits_0^1 e^{-x} dx = -e^{-x}\Big|_0^1 = -e^{-1} + 1.$$
What's wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Your limits of integration have to change too: upon taking $x\to x/n$, the interval of integration is $[0,n]$, and this gives a correct answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!